# Сделал Reset Head hard но забыл закомитить

Tags: android, android-studio, git, git-reset

После изменений решил откатиться и сделал Reset Head hard. И откатился далеко назад. Остался только apk. Можно ли восстановить проект по apk?

Comment: Операция `git reset --hard` вполне себе [обратима](http://tonyganch.com/git/reset/), нужно уметь читать рефлог.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Желательно: перед тем, как начинать работать с репозиторием --
>   сделайте резервную копию всего каталога, чтобы можно было
>   предварительно попрактиковаться на копии или вернуть старое состояние.

Если ваши изменения были закоммичены (достаточно даже только локально, без отправки в удалённый репозиторий), то вполне можно к ним вернуться, даже после того, как откатитесь далеко назад. (При условии, что не были запущены операции очистки репозитория от ненужных/устаревших ссылок -- они обычно хранятся 30 дней).

Всё, что нужно для этого -- это запомнить две простые команды:

```
git reflog
```

и

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{123}
```

Возможно, пригодится такая статья, я по ней изучал когда-то возможности возврата: [git reset: повернуть время вспять](http://tonyganch.com/git/reset/)